# Magento 2: display numeric custom attribute as slider (just like price slider)

Tags: magento2, attributes, price, custom, slider

[image]

I need to make a slider for my numeric custom attribute 'width'. Just like the price slider(in layered navigation) in the theme above.

Comment: How have you get price slider??

Comment: It has been implemented by the theme I bought. Did not implement it myself.

Comment: Okay............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElasticSuite extension: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite adds possibility to create numeric attributes, and filter them using sliders in layered navigation.

Comment: Can you please let me know, How to configure custom attribute as a price slider in the layered navigation?

Comment: @SunnyRahevar based on their documentation: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/wiki/Attribute-configuration . Your  attribute values must be exclusively digits and you must specify that your attribute is using "Decimal Number" as input validation, or "price" as input type. Set the(Input Validation For Store Owner) "Input validation" to "Decimal Number"